# What does. DM- nu, sigma = 10^-33 m_DM GeV^-1 cm^2. mean?

Tags: cosmology, astronomy, dark-matter

[image]

I tried posting a screenshot above......

On Ethan Siegel's blog over at Forbes, he has repeatedly posted a graphic showing possible 'new physics' that could explain why the Planck satellite collaboration says the Hubble 'constant' is about 67, while those using the distance-ladder method get a result of 73.

It Starts With a Bang.    How fast is the Universe expanding?  Incompatible results could point to new physics.   September, 2019

The only part I can't understand is what I have posted here...

DM minus nu,sigma = 10-to-the-33rd m-subscript-DM GeV^-1 cm-squared

Comment: There is a *lot* going on there. Do you understand any of it?

Comment: mDM can mean mixed dark matter, minimal dark matter, or millicharged dark matter.  Do you know which of the three it refers to in this case?

Comment: I would have expected $m_\text{DM}$ to be the *mass of dark matter*...

Comment: What @Kyle siad: there is information in the typesetting as well as in the letters and symbols. Toward that end we have MathJax running on the site so that you can write mathematics here. For instance, if you put `\text{DM}-\nu,\sigma = 10^{-33} m_\text{DM}\,\mathrm{GeV^{-1}\,cm^2}` between dollar signs (`$`) you get $\text{DM}-\nu,\sigma = 10^{-33} m_\text{DM}\,\mathrm{GeV^{-1}\,cm^2}$ (where I have taken the liberty of slightly improving the spacing).

Comment: it also might be nice if you trimmed the image to eliminate the black frame

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The relation in question, $DM-\nu,\,\sigma=10^{-33}m_\text{DM}\,\text{GeV}^{-1}\,\text{cm}^2$ is telling you that the [cross-section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_section_(physics)) ($\sigma$, which as units of area) of the interaction of dark matter particle ($DM$) and a neutrino ($\nu$) is assumed to be $10^{-33}$ times the mass of the dark matter ($m_\text{DM}$), which is [measured in GeV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronvolt#Mass) hence the $\text{GeV}^{-1}$. A better way to write this probably would be something like,
$$
\sigma_{\text{DM}-\nu}=10^{-33}\left(\frac{m_\text{DM}}{\text{GeV}}\right)\,\text{cm}^2
$$

Comment: Perhaps it would be better that say that the corss-section is *assumed* to be such-n-so for the purposes of calculating the plotted effect.

Comment: @dmckee done. i did find [this arXiv paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.7597) saying the relation is less than.